# Django Rest Framework trouble with the creation of users

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I made three different views.py variants and in all of them the user is successfully created but in the admin panel I see *Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm*.

**views1.py**

```
class UserCreteSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields = ['email', 'phone', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {"password":
                           {"write_only": True}
                       }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        email = validated_data['email']
        phone = validated_data['phone']
        password = validated_data['password']
        user_obj = User(
            email = email,
            phone = phone
                 )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save()
        return validated_data
```

**views2.py**

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User(**validated_data)
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user
```

**views3.py**

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    return User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Why is it so? All these ways should work

**settings.py**

```
]    
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

    )
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customuser.User'
```

**customuser.User**

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    username = None    
    email = models.EmailField(validators=[email_regex], unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15) 
    is_pro = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone']

    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: Can you add `settings.py` file?

Comment: Maked update code

Comment: Can you show the model definition for `customuser.User`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class UserCreteSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=32, write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields = ('email', 'phone', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        try:
            user = User(**validated_data)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            raise
        return user
```

Comment: This code is working! Why did not the other options work? Is the problem was in `password = serializers.CharField(max_length=32, write_only=True)` ??

Comment: No, you can also do like this. make sure password is coming through and reaching to `set_password` in string format.

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning the `user_obj` object after creating and not `validated_data` which contains the unhashed `password` field in your `create` method in `views1.py`

```
def create(self, validated_data):
                email = validated_data['email']
                phone = validated_data['phone']
                password = validated_data['password']
                user_obj = User(
                    email = email,
                    phone = phone

                )
                user_obj.set_password(password)
                user_obj.save()
                return user_obj
```

Comment: the same result

Comment: Take a look here. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments. Also post your `customuser.User` model definition

Comment: Posted `customuser.User`